# Get Controller name and SQL query in CakePHP's Router file?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

is it possible to execute sql query in CakePHP's router file? query have to select data, regarding controller name.

it is possible to achieve?

**update:** what i need is to use different route regarding url. relation between url and route will be defined in database.

tnx in adv!

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Routes are not meant to do this much work. You need to rethink your approach and move that logic into a controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP - Access to database via bootstrap.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788444/cakephp-access-to-database-via-bootstrap-php)

Comment: it is. administrator can delete this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting in a controller is possible, but it creates overhead, and the idea behind a controller is not routing. Otherwise the routing class wasn't there.

Actually it is an extension of the Router class, so a new class with your connect function that inherits the router class is the best solution.

It is possible to do your routing by lookup the urls in the database. Just make a table with url, controller, action and param. Lookup the current url ( Router::normalize($dispatcher->getUrl()); ) and then connect with Router::connect( "results from the database" )

Regards,
Wouter de Boer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can access database from router file and set dynamically the router as you wish.
To do that you have to write this code in router file:

```
    App::import('Model', 'ModelName');
    $ModelName = new ModelName();
```

Here ModelName is the name of your model from which you want to pull the data.
So now you have the model's object, now you can get the data by calling model function and define the router. For my case I used this code

```
    $data = $ModelName ->find('all'); 
    if(!empty ($data)){
        //pr($events);
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            if($item['ModelName']['field_name']!=""){
                Router::connect("/{$item['ModelName']['field_name']}", array('controller' => 'registrations', 'action' => 'index', $item['ModelName']['anyvalue']));
            }
        }
    }
```

So, you can define your router in your way as your requirement. If you are still in problem, contact me..

Thanks
Behestee